# Keycloak docker containers are unable to discover each others

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, keycloak, docker-container, service-discovery

I have two instances of keycloak running on container each on is running on a single node.
The nodes are bare-metal nodes inside my company network.

keycloak uses TCPPING as discovery protocol.

Since the two containers are running on different nodes, and each instance is pining inside docker default network they are not able to find each other.

I said docker default network because I didn’t specify special network for the two containers.

Any idea how can I make the two instances in this architectural design discover each others!

and I was thinking about docker swarm as a solution.

Comment: Yes you should use docker swarm - unless you can use a private network between both servers - for this case as long as they are separated machines. docker swarm will make things easier in this case

Comment: Ok thank, but I will try to make them join the host network first. If it didn't work, will go to docker swarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two nodes are on the same network and are able to connect to each other, you can get the two container to discover each other using [docker host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

It would be as easy as `docker run --net=host`

Docker host networking makes the container to use the networking of the host node and thus will be allocated an IP address by the DHCP server used by the host node and for all practical purposes , would look like another host in that network.

This allows the two containers to discover each other using TCPPING

Docker swarm would also enable this .Docker swarm basically abstracts multiple host nodes such that you can containers on them as if you are running docker on single host. But that will require `docker-machine` and whole new setup.

Comment: Still trying this solution but I am facing issue probably from selinux

Comment: Best of luck with SELinux config :-)